# Re-evaluate all object records after workflow rule update

Tags: workflow

I recently made a change to the formula for a workflow rule which is triggered each time an object record is updated.

The formula is doing exactly what I want for my test records, so I am ready to have each record run through the workflow so my custom field get the new value.

Have I overlooked a simple way to have each object record re-evaluated without first editing and saving the record?

Comment: Unless something happens that activates workflow on the Object, there's nothing short of batch processing an update/save on the records or using Data Loader to "touch" them as Mike has suggested that's going to cause it to happen except manually opening the record and saving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't think you have not overlooked a simple way to have each object re-evaluated. In the past I've just used the Data Loader to "touch" records in order to force an update. I would be careful about forcing a mass update though, depending on the number of records involved.

Comment: I was really hoping I overlooked something! Thanks for the answer.